# Android ListVIew type of Facebook FriendList

Tags: android, facebook

I have such question, how can I make such kind of ScrollView . On button click, I want to appear scrollview on most part of screen like facebook application friend list and on another click I want to disappear . Which technics I have to choose, or I could make this using simple 
android:orientation=“horizontal” scroll view ? I need some recommendations. 
 [image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) library for this. You can extend SlidingActivity or you can add it in your XML layout like this:

```
<com.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu
    xmlns:sliding="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/slidingmenulayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    sliding:viewAbove="@layout/YOUR_ABOVE_VIEW"
    sliding:viewBehind="@layout/YOUR_BEHIND_BEHIND"
    sliding:touchModeAbove="margin|fullscreen"
    sliding:touchModeBehind="margin|fullscreen"
    sliding:behindOffset="@dimen/YOUR_OFFSET"
    sliding:behindWidth="@dimen/YOUR_WIDTH"
    sliding:behindScrollScale="@dimen/YOUR_SCALE"
    sliding:shadowDrawable="@drawable/YOUR_SHADOW"
    sliding:shadowWidth="@dimen/YOUR_SHADOW_WIDTH"
    sliding:fadeEnabled="true|false"
    sliding:fadeDegree="float"
    sliding:selectorEnabled="true|false"
    sliding:selectorDrawable="@drawable/YOUR_SELECTOR"/>
```

Comment: and if I scroll on horizontal onButton CLick and then disable scroll, will it be a good way ?

Comment: Your ScrollView would be in your "above" Fragment - everything that you do with it wouldn't affect your menu Fragment (unless you want to)